# Как передать значение переменной в другой файл

Tags: php, wordpress

не могу разобраться с такой задачей.
На сайте есть фильтры, после нажатия кнопки поиск, ajax-ом подгружаются результаты, а над результатами появляется блок с сортировкой, я в переменную получаю количество постов после применения фильтров, и хочу сделать так, если это значение null или <=2, то не показывать блок с сортировкой. Я пробовал использование глобальной переменной, и $_POST, но не получилось, возможно я делал это не правильно, либо мой подход изначально неправилен

functions.php

```
add_action('wp_ajax_myfilter', 'new_filter_function');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_myfilter', 'new_filter_function');

function new_filter_function(){

$args['post_type'] = 'houses';

$query = new WP_Query( $args ); 

$numPost = $query->post_count; //ПЕРЕМЕННАЯ КОТОРУЮ Я ХОЧУ ПЕРЕДАТЬ В archive-houses.php
    

if( $query->have_posts() ) :
    
    while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();
    foreach((get_the_terms($post->ID , 'district')) as $category) {}
    $catName = $category->name;?>
        <div class="slider__img">
            <a class="slider__link" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"></a>
            <img src="<?php the_field('houses-img'); ?>" alt="дом">
        </div>
    <?php endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
else :
    echo 'Домов по вашему запросу не найдено =(';
endif;

die();

}
```

archive-houses.php

```
<?php                    
if($numPost == null || $numPost <= 2 ) {
    
} else {
    echo '<div class="col-11 offset-1">
            <div class="sorting__wrapper">
                <div class="searching-results">

                </div>
                <div class="micro-check">
                    <div class="micro-check-title tabs-parent">
                        Сортировать
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>';
}
```

?>

Comment: ну наверное получая ответ от аякса сделать проверку на количество, условие выполняется - вывести фильтр, не выполняется - не вывести)

Comment: и вообще можно сортировку оставить в хтмл-коде, а просто играть с видимостью этого блока. display: none/block или opacity

Comment: @Jean-Claude,  спасибо, передумал делать так, зайду через JS

Answer (score 0):

просто вызывайте $query = new WP_Query( $args ); и $numPost = $query->post_count; из файла archive-houses.php